# How to fetch record id based on combination of 2 columns

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, csom

I want to fetch a record id in a list based on combination of 2 columns  not through REST API.

I have a List A and a List B. We have fetched the employee name and project name from List A into List B.

But now we want to run the update query and in  order to do that we need to pull the record id based on combination of Employee name field and Project Name field.

we cannot use REST API as Project name is a calculated field in List A.

Answer (score 1):

We can use **/_vti_bin/listdata.svc** REST API to achieve it.

Example Code:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    var employeeName="emp1";
    var projectName="P1";
    getListItemId(employeeName,projectName).done(function(itemId){
        alert(itemId);
    });
})
function getListItemId(employeeName,projectName) {
    var deferred=$.Deferred();
    $.ajax({
        url: _spPageContextInfo.siteAbsoluteUrl + "/_vti_bin/listdata.svc/ListA?$filter=EmployeeName eq '"+employeeName+"' and ProjectName eq '"+projectName+"'",
        type: "GET",
        headers: {
            "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
        },
        success: function (data) {          
            var itemId=data.d.results[0].Id;
            deferred.resolve(itemId);

        },
        error: function (err) {
            console.log(JSON.stringify(err));
        }
    });
    return deferred.promise();
}
</script>
```

We can also use CAML query with REST API to achieve it.

Refer to: [SharePoint REST API - CAML Query](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/sharepoint-rest-api-caml-query)

Comment: but my employee name and project name will be dynamic. will this query work for dynamic purpose?

Comment: will you be able to help me in solving this issue?

Comment: I modify the code in my reply above, you can pass the parameters dynamic.

Comment: so Project name is a calculated column, will this code work?

Comment: still not working

Comment: Check the list name and column internal name.

Comment: list name has to be the internal name?

Comment: If the list name is "List A", you need use /_vti_bin/listdata.svc/ListA. More: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/laurieatkinson/2014/06/19/rules-for-the-list-name-used-with-listdata-svc/